# vim: recovering a text file "already at oldest change"

Tags: vim

I am using vim to edit .sh file. Last time, I was making changes I got: "E297: Write error in swap file" and I accidentally managed to erase the content and save.

Now, all I have is .sh .sh~ .su~ .sv~ .sw~ .sy~ .sz~ files with empty content and "E297: Write error in swap file" message. When I do :u, it says: "already at oldest change".

when I do :recover, it says: "E305: no swap file found"

How to recover my file? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately you probably can't. Modern editors do a better job at recovering files, Vim has a lot of hacks to try to get a good experience but it doesn't work well. I would `set backupdir=/tmp` and `set directory=/tmp` so swap files are always writeable. Hopefully this file was version controlled recently enough to have some recovery? =\

Comment: Vim sessions also persist undo history (but are poorly designed and clunky to use). I would also install the Gundo plugin (not worth using vim without this) to see your undo history as a navigable tree (it wouldn't help this specific case, but gives you more control over accidental undo branches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the original file may be recovered using swap files which have the form `.filename.sh.swp`.  These are files that Vim creates to back up in case of a potential crash. In order to recover your original file, try these steps:

1. Look for swap files in the current directory (there could be more than one for a particular file):

   ```
   ls -a
   ```
2. Open the first swap file in Vim from the terminal:

   ```
   vi .filename.sh.swp
   ```

   or alternatively, launch Vim with `vim` and edit the swap file with `:e .filename.sh.swp`.
3. From within the swap file type  `:recover`. Now Vim will load the recovered file on a new buffer. If this is the file that you needed then simply save the file `:w`.

It could be that the recovered file is not exactly the latest version of your `filename.sh`, in this case  repeat steps 2 and 3 above with a different swap file e.g. `.filename.sh.swo`. Once the desired file has been recovered removed the swap files.

These help pages are also relevant for recovering files: 
    :help swap
    :help recover
    :help e305

Comment: The `foo~` files are *backup* files, not swap files.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Unfortunately, there is no .swp or .swo files. When I do  vim .filename.sh.swp it is an empty file and when i do :recover it says: E306: Cannot open demo_multiple.sh.swp